# How to copy files from virtual server

Tags: linux, winscp

I'm connected from my machine (windows 10) to linux server through putty. On linux I can connect to virtual server via: ssh vpn. I created a few files on this vpn server and now I need copy these files to my flash disk. Please how proceed? I trying connect via winscp, but not successfully.

Please help, many thanks.

PP

Comment: How, exactly, does WinSCP not connect successfully?

Comment: Do you connect with a password or with an SSH key?

Answer (score 0):

Do you connect to Linux server using ssh protocol on putty? If yes then 99% you can sftp or scp to it (using WinSCP on Windows). Check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file on Linux for lines with `sftp`, for example `ForceCommand internal-sftp` or `Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server`. If none of them is present add them or uncomment them if they are commented. Then restart sshd, `systemctl restart ssh` or `service ssh restart`. Be careful that you might lose connection when restarting.